# DioError [DioErrorType.other]: FormatException: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter

[image]

my json file is as bellow. but i got this error

Comment: could you include the part that you get the data from api response?

Comment: Future<List<ProductEntity>> getAll(int sort)async {
  final response=await HttpClient.get('/kafsh');
  //final response2= await json.encode(response.data);  
  validateResponse(response);
  final products=<ProductEntity>[];
  (response as List).forEach((element) {
    products.add(ProductEntity.FromJson(element));
  });
  return products;
  }